# How can I create a graphic representation of frames in an encoded video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

ffprobe is great but I couldn't get it to show a 1-liner info of each frame, let alone a graphic representation.
Is there some software that can either take the json output of ffprobe and show it graphically or analyze a h.264 stream and show it graphically?
I'm looking at types of frames, sizes etc...

And preferably I'm looking for a tool for Mac.

Comment: What all info do you need from a frame?

Comment: type of frame and size

Comment: This may also be interesting: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly get a 1-line readout per frame from ffprobe. Use

```
ffprobe -v 16 -show_entries frame=pict_type,pkt_size,pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 in.mp4
```

This will generate an output like this

```
1.600000,55307,I
1.640000,5610,B
1.680000,19691,B
1.720000,24077,B
1.760000,39859,P
1.800000,24254,B
1.840000,31068,B
1.880000,29013,B
1.920000,43124,P
1.960000,35221,B
```

This first entry is the timestamp, then the packet size for the frame and the type. You can use Excel or any similar tool to generate a graph.